# How do you sort an array alphabetically using sort_by in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, sorting, enumerable

I have an array of memberships. In each membership is a group. I need to sort this array of memberships by the name of the group. I've tried a bunch of different ways, and the latest way is this:

```
@memberships.sort_by! { |m| m.group.name }
```

However, this doesn't sort by the name. It appears to be randomly sorting the array.

- Membership belongs_to :group
- Group has_many :memberships

@memberships is equal to:

```
[
  {
  id: 2141,
  user_id: 491,
  group_id: 271,
  member_type: "member",
    group: {
      id: 271,
      name: "Derek's",
      privacy: "open",
      bio_image_url: "/bio_images/medium/missing.png?1340285189",
      member_count: 1,
      upcoming_checkins_count: 0
    }
  },
  {
  id: 2201,
  user_id: 221,
  group_id: 291,
  member_type: "member",
    group: {
      id: 291,
      name: "Rounded Developement",
      privacy: "closed",
      bio_image_url: "/groups/medium/291/bioimage.jpg?1340736175",
      member_count: 7,
      upcoming_checkins_count: 0
   }
}
]
```

NOTE: This does work --> @memberships.sort_by! { |m| m.group.id }

It will order the array based on the group.id so maybe it has something to do with sorting alphabetically?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Wow, after struggling with this for an extremely long time, I realized my problem was a simple one. I was sorting by group.name but some of the group names were uppercase and some were lower, which was throwing it all off. Converting everything to downcase worked well.

```
@memberships.sort_by!{ |m| m.group.name.downcase }
```

Comment: Award yourself the answer when the system will let you.

Comment: Downcase is the way to go +1

Comment: The `.downcase` method is very important because other wise the sorting stuff will behave weird for some elements.

Answer (score 3):

Is the sort method an option?

```
ary.sort{ |a,b| a[:group][:name] <=> b[:group][:name] }
```

Comment: I tried that as well..     `@memberships.sort { |a,b| a.group.name <=> b.group.name }` still doesn't work tho.

Comment: Forgot the nesting... I corrected by adding the parent group key

Comment: Okay, maybe this is the problem– something I didn't mention. When I do a.group.name I am performing a join between the memberships and groups table. So, would that have an effect on the result sorting? Cause it still won't work with the updated code.

Comment: So you're not sorting the resulting array of hashes, but the ActiveRecord objects, correct?  Maybe try using "order"

`Membership.joins(:groups).order("groups.name")`

Comment: I ended up figuring it out. It was a stupid problem. I didn't realize sort didn't take into account upper and lower case. So I could figure out why it looked like this: [Ash, Bob, Jim, anna, kim] – I ended up sorting by downcase. Thanks for your help (sorry to bother ya with something silly like this!)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how your code is working. I can't access the hashes in the arrays using `m.group.name`

Here's a working syntax

```
@memberships.sort_by!{ |m| m[:group][:name] }
```

Comment: ah, i think i should revise my question. when i do m.group i am performing a sql join

Comment: in any case, that still doesn't correctly sort by name. it appears to be random (im sure there is a method to its madness).